# Minimal Number of Transactions to Settle Outstanding Poker Game

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization

There are several players at the end of the poker night with wins and losses, with zero sum. What is the optimal solution to settle the balance that minimize the total number of transactions (eg. if we consider a transaction as a venmo payment).

```
name  | balance (N means how much net win, negative means lost)
A     | -200
B     | +100   <- biggest winner
C     | -50 
D     | +25
E     | +75
F     | +50
```

**Solution1: 12 constant**

One naive solution is to have a central bank every everyone buys in before the game and cashes out in the end, there will require a constant 2*n transactions - 12 transactions in this case.

**Solution2: 5 pay the biggest winner**

Another better solution is to have all the losers pays the biggest winner, then the winner gives to other smaller winners.

Transactions needed will be 5:

```
Send -> Receive | Amount
A -> B          | 200 
C -> B          | 50
B -> D          | 25
B -> E          | 50
B -> F          | 50
```

**Solution3: 4 cancel out?**

Just by the look at the amount, a better solution only takes 4 transactions:

```
Send -> Receive | Amount
A -> B          | 100 
A -> D          | 25
A -> E          | 75
C -> F          | 50
```

Thoughts:
I feel this is related to a graph problem but also looks like a linear planning, but I lack the proper knowledge background to tell if a proper algorithm exists.

```
    A    B    C    D    E    F   Sum
A                               -200
B                               -50                          
C                                0
D                                0
E                                0
F                                0
Sum  0  +100   0  +25   +75  +50
```

Minimize the number of populated cells.

Comment: Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877728/what-algorithm-to-use-to-determine-minimum-number-of-actions-required-to-get-the/)

Comment: @Nathaniel, the answer from mbiron in your post is particularly interesting. It showed a solution of using LP to find/approximate the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is [strongly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_NP-completeness) NP-hard.

A set of transactions can be regarded as a directed graph. Let $A$ be the set of vertices corresponding to players with positive losses and let $B$ be the set of vertices corresponding to players with positive wins.
The number of transactions is at least $\max(|A|,|B|)$ because each vertex in $A$ must have at least one outgoing edge, and each vertex in $B$ must have at least one incoming edge.

Suppose $|A| \geq |B|$ and there is a solution with $|A|$ transactions.
Then, every $a \in A$ has exactly one outgoing edge.
For each $b \in B$, let $A_b$ be the set of vertices reachable to $b$ then the sum of losses in $A_b$ is equal to the win of $b$.
That is because there are no outgoing edges from $A_b$ other than $b$, and $b$ has no outgoing edges.

With these facts, a reduction from the [3-partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem) is straightforward.
We have positive integers $a_1, \dots, a_{3m}$ and $t = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{3m} a_i$ with restriction: $t/2 < a_i < t/4$ for each $i$. The 3-partition problem with restriction is strongly NP-hard.

We create $3m$ players $A$ with losses $(a_i)_i$, and $m$ players $B$ with wins $t$.
The 3-partition problem instance has a solution if and only if there is a set of $3m$ transactions clearing all wins and losses.

For a 3-partition $(A_i)_{i=1}^m$, we can make $3m$ transactions of from $\{ a \rightarrow b_i \mid i \in [m], a \in A_i \}$.

Conversely, for a solution with $|A| = 3m$ transactions, we have a solution to the 3-partition problem instance as $\{A_b \mid b \in B \}$. The sum of integers is $t$ as shown above, and we have $|A_b| = 3$ due to the restriction.